# Swift message sent to deallocated instance – Every IBAction

Tags: ios, swift

Every time I add an @IBAction to a view controller in my Swift project, I get an error (with NSZombies): `[Shaan_Singh.SkillsViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f936380c170`. Why is this happening? All I'm trying to do is connect an IBAction to a button. Any ideas?

Code:

```
@IBAction func doSomething(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("some")
}
```

Here's the code that calls the view controller:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

        for var l = 0; l < self.view.layer.sublayers.count; l++ {
            let hitLayer = CGPathContainsPoint(self.view.layer.sublayers[l].path, nil, location, true)

            if hitLayer == true {
                // Play sound
                audioPlayer.play()

                // Configure animation
                let endShape = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight)).CGPath
                let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
                animation.toValue = endShape
                animation.duration = 0.4
                animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

                // Fire animation
                if let shapeLayer = self.view.layer.sublayers[l] as? CALayer {
                    shapeLayer.zPosition = 1
                    shapeLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
                }

                // Segue to view controller
                if l == 5 {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("shape1", sender: self)
                } else if l == 1 {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("shape2", sender: self)
                } else if l == 6 {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("shape3", sender: self)
                } else if l == 0 {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("shape4", sender: self)
                } else if l == 4 {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("shape5", sender: self)
                } else if l == 3 {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("shape6", sender: self)
                } else if l == 2 {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("shape7", sender: self)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code which causes the crash.

Comment: Which line of code causes the crash?

Comment: @rdelmar The IBAction.

Comment: This is the third question in the last day that you asked about basically the same problem. Either your Xcode is seriously screwed up, or you're doing something you're not telling us about that is causing these problems. There' nothing in the code you post that is useful to solve the problem. You should upload this project or a simple app that exhibits the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a lot more information. How is the view controller that this button links to created?

Somehow your view controller is getting deallocated.

Post the code that creates your view controller and displays it to the screen, along with the declaration of the variable that holds a reference to the view controller.

My guess is that you create a view controller, install it's view as a subview of another view controller, then return, so that the view controller gets released out from under it's view. (If you don't keep a strong reference to the view controller it will be deallocated, causing exactly the problem you describe.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. I create my view controller in storyboard. I have MenuVC --> DetailVC. MenuVC just does a `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detail", sender: self)` to DetailVC. Besides that, I don't do anything else to create the VC.

Comment: What should I do to instantiate it?

Comment: Okay, using this seemed to work: `var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("skills") as! SkillsViewController`
`self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`. But, how do I integrate that with my segue?

Comment: Edit your original question and post the full method that creates the view controller, along with the declaration of the variable that creates it.

Comment: That's the thing. I never created the view controller. Never assigned it a variable. Just segued. Now I know that's wrong, trying to figure out the right way to do this.

Comment: If you use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` that is code that creates a view controller. This is the last time I'm going to ask. Post the entire method that contains the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier call, if that's how you create your view controller, and then also post the declaration of the variable or constant the saves a reference to that view controller.

Comment: Okay, I posted the code. I don't think I used `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` or saved a reference to the view controller.

Comment: In your comment above you specifically said you were using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

Comment: Yes, I was just now trying out some different methods. `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` seemed to present the view controller and solve all the problems. However, how do I use this with my segue (rather than presenting the view controller)

Comment: What kind of segues are you invoking? (modal, push, etc)

Comment: Modal segues. I'm using iOS 8 without AutoLayout.